# Azure Devops Cli Docker registry service connection fails

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am try to create Service Connection for Docker Registry in Azure Devops using Azure Cli. I could create the service connection but it is not accepting the password passed via config.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not share your `config.json` here, I would share you mine that is work fine on my side:

```
{
  "id": "06111f22-xxx-fba560f7d470",
  "description": "",
  "administratorsGroup": null,
  "authorization": {
    "parameters": {
      "username": "xxxx",
      "password": "xxxxxx",
      "email": "",
      "registry": "https://index.docker.io/v1/"
    },
    "scheme": "UsernamePassword"
  },
  "createdBy": null,
  "data": {
    "registrytype": "DockerHub"
  },
  "name": "Dockerhub",
  "type": "dockerregistry",
  "url": "https://hub.docker.com/",
  "readersGroup": null,
  "groupScopeId": null,
  "serviceEndpointProjectReferences": null,
  "operationStatus": null
}
```

In this `config.jso`n file, the password must be the **clear text**. After created, you can go UI, then click on **Verify this connection** to see whether it is created succeed:

[image]

---

For the command output which displayed after you create the service connection via cli:

[image]

You can ignore this `null` output, which is actually the output we set to protect the user's privacy data from being intercepted and parsed, which will cause data theft. This is as design by us.

In fact, the password has stored in the backend database in the background after you create it. It is just represented as `null` in the data interaction with the frontend. Just for security protected.

To confirm whether it is created successfully, you can follow the method I show above. Go UI, then click on **Verify this connection** to see whether it is an available service connection.

Comment: Thanks Sir ... actually now that Password is working fine  .... now that “allow access to pipeline “ option is not getting enabled is there an way to enable them via CLI

Comment: @viswanathanand Of course yes, Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/devops/service-endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-devops-service-endpoint-update. Set **--enable-for-all** as **true** in update command to allow all pipelines to access this service endpoint.

Comment: Liang : Thanks Sir for the link is there any way to find the service connection Endpoint ID via some command or script?

Comment: @viswanathanand, After you create the service connection via azure cli, it prompts some outputs, right? You can find the service connection id from that: https://imgur.com/a/YdElUQN

Comment: Yes Thanks @Merlin Liang for helping me to debug on the same it really helps

Comment: Thanks @Merlin Liang able to solve the issue by using azure cli method to find the endpoint ID and update it.